# Map with dynamic value type?

Tags: dictionary, go, dynamic, interface

Is there any way to create a map with a dynamic value type, to store in a single map both float and string values?

```
myMap["key"] = 0.25
myMap["key2"] = "some string"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `interface{}` as the value for the map which will store any type of value you pass and then use type assertion to fetch the underlying value.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    myMap := make(map[string]interface{})
    myMap["key"] = 0.25
    myMap["key2"] = "some string"
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", myMap)
    // fetch value using type assertion
    fmt.Println(myMap["key"].(float64))
    fetchValue(myMap)
}

func fetchValue(myMap map[string]interface{}){
    for _, value := range myMap{
        switch v := value.(type) {
            case string:
                fmt.Println("the value is string =", value.(string))
            case float64:
                fmt.Println("the value is float64 =", value.(float64))
            case interface{}:
                fmt.Println(v)
            default:
                fmt.Println("unknown")
        }
    }
}
```

Working code on [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/irgeuViBCiz)

> Variables of interface type also have a distinct dynamic type, which
>   is the concrete type of the value assigned to the variable at run time
>   (unless the value is the predeclared identifier nil, which has no
>   type). The dynamic type may vary during execution but values stored in
>   interface variables are always assignable to the static type of the
>   variable.

```
var x interface{}  // x is nil and has static type interface{}
var v *T           // v has value nil, static type *T
x = 42             // x has value 42 and dynamic type int
x = v              // x has value (*T)(nil) and dynamic type *T
```

If you do not the type use switch to fetch the value as:

```
func question(anything interface{}) {
    switch v := anything.(type) {
        case string:
            fmt.Println(v)
        case int32, int64:
            fmt.Println(v)
        case SomeCustomType:
            fmt.Println(v)
        default:
            fmt.Println("unknown")
    }
}
```

you can add as many types you want in the switch case to get the value

Comment: Thanks!
and if i will need to convert the value to string(or something) and i don't know what type is the value can i do it ?
for example if i will loop all the map and trying to print every value to console?

Comment: @Martin yes you can use switch to fetch the value if you do not know the type.

Comment: @Martin you can check my edited answer where you can get the type of value.

Comment: fyi, there is also sync.Map which acts like map[interface{}]interface{} but also provides sync guaranties.

Comment: @Mikhail yes there is but it is preferred not to use it until you want to use its all embedded functionalities or you are using it with go routines.